# Missing include gives no compile error on RedHat 6

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, redhat, numeric

This snippet can not be compiled, since [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is found in the header `numeric`, which is not included.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> vec{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(),0);
}
```

The [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MW3DuY) gives me the correct error message

```
<source>(6): error: namespace "std" has no member "accumulate"
      return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(),0);
```

I am using RedHat 6 and the intel compiler version 18.0.3. If I compile it with this setting, I get no error and the result is fine. No warning is shown, even if `-Wall` is used.

My question is, why don't I get an appropriate error message?

Comment: Maybee the used intel libs are implemented another way so the desired header is included indirectly?

Comment: The error-message seams to be clear: `std::accumulate`does not exist.

Comment: @MrSmith42 My problem is, that I don't get this error message on my system (RedHat6, intel compiler). It compiles although it should not.

Comment: You are wrong to say "it should not". It would still be conforming if an implementation defined the entire standard library in one giant header and then both of `<vector>` and `<algorithm>` included that giant header. All you can say is that the program is not guaranteed to compile, you can't say it's guaranteed to _not_ compile.

Comment: Compilers are not conscious, not aware of the standard, and not guaranteed to be free of implementation flaws.    Being able to detect all flaws in its accompanying implementation of the standard library is also beyond capability of most compilers.   After all, if such a thing was possible, all compilers and libraries would be shipped with perfect compliance to the standard, and updating for compliance to a new version of the standard would be simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why don't I get an appropriate error message?

Because one of the standard library headers `<algorithm>` or `<vector>` that you use for compilation do include `<numeric>` themselves. This is a common portability issue; your code happens to compile with a particular standard library implementation, but fails to build with another one. Library implementations are free to include standard headers in standard headers. Maybe some functionality in your `<algorithm>` was implemented using any of the `<numeric>` algorithms, and there you are.

The compiler error you encounter is the reason tools like [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org/) exist. Using `iwyu` her would add `#include <numeric>` to your snippet. Note also that no warning flags will influence the result of the compilation. Either you get a hard compiler error or nothing.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this a very nontrivial problem to solve. IWYU does the best it can but there are still [plenty](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/issues) of corner cases where it will "fail".

Comment: @MaxLanghof - One way to increase chances of detecting such concerns, as well as other portability concerns, is to build the code with multiple compilers - ideally all configured to emit as many warnings/errors as possible.   While there are no guarantees, a set of compilers and their standard libraries from different developers/vendors are pretty unlikely to all have the same the same set of flaws.

Comment: @Peter The same issue exists for your own code though. It's extremely easy to use things that your current includes brought in without adding the necessary includes yourself. Then the code can (and will) randomly break not when compilers are changed but when something somewhere deep down in your includes moves an include from `.h` to `.cpp` or similar. But you are of course right that portability problems can be found by verifying portability.