# C++ template arguments not recognized

Tags: c++, templates

In Visual Studio using C++ 20 I have a template class for implementing matrix maths defined in the header TMatrix.h

It looks like this:

**Header TMatrix.h**

```
template <class X> class TMatrix {

private :

long min_adr_row; 
long max_adr_row; 


/**********************************************************************/
/*** TMatrix public ***************************************************/
/**********************************************************************/
//
public:
   
long     row;                     
long     col;                       

X     **data;                       


 TMatrix (const long & m = 0,              
             const long & n = 0);
 TMatrix (const TMatrix<X> & A);          
~TMatrix (void);                        


// ... other methods

};
```

This header compiles without errors.

In another header I have a function declaration that should return an object of the type TMatrix<double>. It looks like this:

**Header SomeFunctions.h**

```
#include  "TMatrix.h"

TMatrix<double> Get_HC(long ind_, TMatrix<double> L_HC_);
```

In another header there is a global variable of the type TMatrix<double>. It looks like this:

**Header SomeGlobals.h**

```
#include  "TMatrix.h"

TMatrix<double> G_2_TOOL_(1000, 4);
```

In both cases I get the following build error: *error C7568: argument list missing after assumed function template 'TMatrix'.*

From my understanding I have provided the type "double" as the template argument "X".

Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?

EDIT: I added the definition of the first constructor to the header TMatrix.h. The error seems to come from there.

```
template <class X> TMatrix<X>::TMatrix(const long & m, const long & n) {


/*** Initialisierungen ************************************************/

row         =    m;
col         =    n;
min_adr_row =   -1;
max_adr_row =   -1;
data        = NULL;


/*** Speicher allozieren **********************************************/

if ((row > 0) && (col > 0)){ 

   /***** Speicher fuer 1. Dimension *****/
   
   data = (X **) calloc(row, sizeof(X *));
   if (!data){
      this->Error("TMatrix<X> (Konstruktor)", "Speicherallokation 1. Dimension fehlgeschlagen");
   }
   min_adr_row = (long) &data;
   max_adr_row = min_adr_row + (row-1)*sizeof(X *);


   /***** Speicher fuer 2. Dimension *****/
   
   for (long i = 0; i < row; i++){
      data[i] = (X *) calloc(col, sizeof(X));
      if (!data[i]){
         this->Error("TMatrix<X> (Konstruktor)", "Speicherallokation 2. Dimension fehlgeschlagen");
      }
   }

} else{

   if ((row < 0) || (col < 0)){
      row = 0;
      col = 0;
      this->Error("TMatrix<X> (Konstruktor)", "[(row < 0) || (col < 0)]");
   }

} /*** Ende if ((row > 0) && ... ***/


return;
}
```

GDB gives me the error: TMatrix.h:52:18: error: there are no arguments to ‘calloc’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘calloc’ must be available [-fpermissive]
52 |    data = (X **) calloc(row, sizeof(X *));
|                  ^~~~~~

Can someone explain to me what this error means? This is way to deep for me and I have no idea what the person who wrote this constructor was doing. Also why is VS not showing me this?

Comment: Program [works here](https://onlinegdb.com/fs4gNzZID)

Comment: "assumed function template 'TMatrix'" means the compiler assumes, for some reason, that `TMatrix` is a function template, and "argument list missing" complains about missing function arguments

Comment: please make sure to post a [mcve]. Can you reproduce the error with only the code you included here?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So can I assume that the header TMatrix.h which contains the template class has in fact not compiled correctly and for some reason VS is not showing me this in the output? Otherwise the compiler should now that TMatrix<double> is a class and not a function template right?

Comment: @ST11280709 Try building/compiling your program from terminal and see if it works. If it does, that should confirm that the problem is with IDE(its settings/config etc).

Comment: Thanks I will try. If that is in fact the case how could I find the error in the settings? BTW everything I posted refers to the building process using "Local Windows Debugger" with setting Auto

Comment: @ST11280709 typically attempt of making that minimal example will show you what error you made. We can not guess it as you did not post that part in your question.

Comment: Your template class is abstract. You have to define c-tor, d-tor and other methods.

Comment: You don't compile headers in isolation - you need to consider what gets included through all the headers in the source files that include these files and check what's in there.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I think I was able to reproduce the error. Please see the edit I made at the end of the original question.

Comment: I don't get an error when I run the code in the link.

Comment: @ST11280709 The link you gave does not reproduces the error.

Comment: @NathanOliver realized my sillyness and comment is removed

Comment: @ST11280709 Do you have TMatrix.h where you have declared the template and then a TMatrix.cpp file where you defined everything for the template?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce an error. I tried to include the other headers, added missing definitions (which caused a different error) and it compiles fine https://onlinegdb.com/OGdWxlIw3

Comment: Sorry my bad guys I didn't save my work on online GDB. I added the definition and the error it gives on the original question instead now.

Comment: " there are no arguments to ‘calloc’ that depend on a template parameter, s" thats a totally different error now. You missed to include the header and because its inside a template the compiler has a very convoluted way to tell you it has no idea what `calloc` is.

Comment: if you miss to include a header it can work by chance. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786341/missing-include-gives-no-compile-error-on-redhat-6

Comment: Ok now I cannot reproduce it either after adding the included headers. @NathanOliver No the entire implementation is in the header. I am giving up now. Can someone tell me how I can make Visual Studio 2019 switch back to C++ 11 Standard. Because before I changed to a newer standard the code worked.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Thanks, that is very interesting and very unsettling.

Comment: what is it actually that you are struggling with now? THe error about "C7568: argument list missing after assumed function template 'TMatrix'." ? We need to see some code that produces this error, then we can help you fix it

Comment: You can't set MSVS to anything lower that C++14.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Thanks for the offer, but the problem is that I don't know what code exactly it is that causes this error and the entire project consists of 20+ modules with several thousand lines of code which I cannot post here. I will try to reproduce the error by uploading more code step by step in the GDB tool tomorrow and if I can reproduce it I will let you know.

Comment: Please show the complete and unedited output of the compiler, including file names and line numbers.